# Setting nested value in NSDictionary that is in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I would like to do this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue@"nextFoo" forKeyPath@"values.foo"];
```

...

values was shoved into defaults earlier in the code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *values = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[values setObject@"firstFoo" forKey:@"foo"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:values forKey:@"values"];
```

I am guessing that regardless of the fact that I shoved a Mutable Dictionary into user defaults it gets stored as an immutable dictionary.  I am trying to take a shortcut to allow me set a nested value without getting the values dictionary as mutable, setting the value there and then setting values again, i.e. longer version that I am trying to get around

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *values = [[defaults objectForKey:@"values"] mutableCopy];
[values setObject@"nextFoo" forKey:@"foo"];
[defaults setObject:values forKey:@"values"];  // set the entire values dictionary again, even though I really only needed to set one nested value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common mistake, but you need to use the `setObject:` methods for NSUserDefaults, not `setValue:` and so the `setValue:forKeyPath:` also won't be of help to you. You'll need to just fetch the dictionary out and set the value then re-set the dictionary.

Comment: Why do you suggest to not use setValue:forKeyPath: to update a nested value in NSUserDefaults and why do you consider it a mistake? It actually works.

Comment: @ggould75 that's a method for Key-Value coding, not setting information into the user defaults dictionary. It might run, but it won't store anything in the user defaults object for you. AFAIK...

Comment: @Acey You are right. I was looking at my old code where I was using setValue:forKeyPath: but only later realised I was also including this category https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/blob/master/NSUserDefaults%2BKeyPaths.h which internally use the standard setObject:forKey.